# Cloud Functions for Firebase: serializing Promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In an onWrite handler, I'd like to perform multiple reads, manipulate some data, and then store it. I'm fairly new to the Promise concept. Am I safe with the following Promise handling, in regards to Firebase not killing my queries before they're done?

```
exports.test = functions.database.ref('/zzz/{uid}').onWrite(event => {
    console.log('zzz', event.data.val());

    return Promise.all([
        admin.database().ref('/zzz/1').once('value'),
        admin.database().ref('/zzz/2').once('value')
    ]).then(function(snaps) {
        console.log('loaded', snaps[0].val());
        var updKeys = {
            ["/xxx/" +event.params.uid +"/zoo"]: 'giraffe',
        }

        admin.database().ref().update(updKeys, function(error) {
            console.log("Updating data finished. ", error || "Success.");
        })
    });

});
```

The above works, but not sure its the right way...

Comment: I'm curious why you're requesting `/zzz/2` when you never use `snaps[1]`...?

Comment: It's just a test - don't mind the actual (mis)usage of retrieved data (or the ugly fact its using hardcoded uids :)

Comment: Also note that the promise you're returning from your `onWrite` callback is resolved **before** the `update` at the end is complete. If that's not intentional, you'll need to create a promise, return it from `then`, and resolve it in the `update` callback.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'd love to see an example of how its done. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I can't really answer the question you've asked (I don't know anything about when Firebase kills queries). If you want to ask a question about promises, I could answer that. Basically within the `then` you'd do `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { /*...your current 'then' code here...*/});` and call `resolve` (or `reject`) from within the `update` callback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your Function continues to execute after it has returned (or the promise that your function returns has resolved), Google Cloud Functions *may* interrupt your code at any time. There is however no guarantee that it *will* do so immediately.

In your code sample, you return the result of the final `then()`. Since you don't return anything from within that `then()` block, GCF may interrupt the call to `update()` *or* it may continue to let the code run longer than is needed.

To correct this, make sure to "bubble up" the promise from the `update()` call:

```
exports.test = functions.database.ref('/zzz/{uid}').onWrite(event => {
    console.log('zzz', event.data.val());

    return Promise.all([
        admin.database().ref('/zzz/1').once('value'),
        admin.database().ref('/zzz/2').once('value')
    ]).then(function(snaps) {
        console.log('loaded', snaps[0].val());
        var updKeys = {
            ["/xxx/" +event.params.uid +"/zoo"]: 'giraffe',
        }

        return admin.database().ref().update(updKeys, function(error) {
            console.log("Updating data finished. ", error || "Success.");
        })
    });

});
```

In this code, the promise returned by `update()` is the one being returned to GCF, which gives it the information to leave your function running for precisely as long as it needs.

Comment: Ah! Missed a return. Thanks!  :)
Also, was wondering about which tag goes with firebase-functions, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the naming is confusing. Sorry about that. Also see my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854865/what-is-the-difference-between-cloud-function-and-firebase-functions/42859932#42859932

Comment: I was using `event.data.adminRef.root.child('/x')`, but is it possible to use `admin.database().ref('/x')` here?