# Botbuilder doesn't respond after sending 'accepted' code when using cloud functions

Tags: firebase, botframework, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Dialogflow as the handler for my botbuilder endpoint, which is a Azure Bot Service bot, and the handler is deployed on a Firebase Cloud Function, but for every botframework request I make, the function returns a 202 (that's the default behaviour of botbuilder I believe), and the function stops working in the middle of the code.
I saw in this response from [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) that the functions may halt if there's a response from the function.
[Cloud Functions for Firebase: serializing Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875400/cloud-functions-for-firebase-serializing-promises)

Is this enough to stop my function from executing? If so, is there a way to stop this from happening?

Edit: I'm using the Universal Bot to setup the callback for the messages.

`const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(this.connector, botFrameworkCallback)
        .set('storage', new builder.MemoryBotStorage());`

And here's the `botFrameworkCallback`:

```
const botFrameworkCallback = (session) => {
  const message = session.message.text;
  const userRef = new UserRef('user');
  let userInfo;
  userRef
    .get()
    .then((userInformation) => {
      console.log('user information', userInformation);
      userInfo = userInformation;
      const userData: IUser = {
        ...userInfo,
        ref: userRef
      };
      return makeDialogflowRequest(userData, message);
    })
    .then((intentResult: any) => {
      console.log('intent result', intentResult);
      const response = intentResult.answer;
      session.send(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error on BotFramework', err);
      const response = 'Sorry. An error happened while getting your response.';
      session.send(response);
    });
}
```

The whole integration part is there to give user specific responses, so this code does a lot of API requests, like Firestore ones, the Dialogflow one, and because of that we've set it up this way.

Comment: It's difficult to imagine what's going on here without seeing your code.

Comment: Hi, Doug. Just added a code sample of the bot endpoint.

Comment: Hi, Doug. Did the code help you finding the problem?