# How to split firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I'm working with firebase functions and it is very hard to mange it index.js

`index.js` files like:

> index.js

I want to be `index.js` and ***sub domain routing in `apitest.js` with express.js***

> index.js 
>   apis -> test.js

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = express();
...
const funcTestApi = require('./apis/apitest');

exports.apitest = functions.https.onRequest(app => {
    funcTestApi.router(app);
});
```

**apitest.js**

```
exports.router = function(app) {
    app.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).json('hello');
    });

    app.get('/bar', (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).json('world');
    });

    ... // other url route 
}
```

**Log:**

```
http http://localhost:5000/project-name/us-central1/apitest/foo
http http://localhost:5000/project-name/us-central1/apitest/bar
...

info: Execution took 60000 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
```

It's not working.

Comment: Take a look at the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486278/how-do-i-structure-cloud-functions-for-firebase-to-deploy-multiple-functions-fro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I structure Cloud Functions for Firebase to deploy multiple functions from multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486278/how-do-i-structure-cloud-functions-for-firebase-to-deploy-multiple-functions-fro)

Comment: Thank for your replay @ScottKronheim But, I want to know about sub domain router in apitest.js with express.js In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486278/how-do-i-structure-cloud-functions-for-firebase-to-deploy-multiple-functions-fro) there is no way about split http functions

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Write return code, then it's work

**apitest.js**

```
exports.router = function(app) {
    app.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).json('hello');
    });

    app.get('/bar', (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).json('world');
    });

    ... // other url route 

    return app; // <-- here
}
```