# Firebase Function import function from other file - javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am building firebase function with javascript. Now i have a lot of inter-call function and i plan to move those function into different file to avoid index.js become very messy.

So below is the current file structure:

```
/functions
   |--index.js
   |--internalFunctions.js
   |--package.json
   |--package-lock.json
   |--.eslintrc.json
```

I want to know:

1) How to export the function from internalFunctions.js and import it to index.js.

2) How to call internalFunctions.js function from index.js.

My code is written in JavaScript.

**Edited**

internalFunction.js will have multiple functions.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486278/how-do-i-structure-cloud-functions-for-firebase-to-deploy-multiple-functions-fro

Comment: Which one is the appropriate solution? because the accepted answer's comment actually telling my concern, which i don want to export the internalFunctions.js functions again in index.js. I want to call a function in internalFunctions.js from index.js only.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more explicit, I added an answer, you can see that the importing is the same as the post except that you need to use it differently.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First you set the function in your file:

**internalFunctions.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    HelloWorld: function test(event) {
        console.log('hello world!');
    }
};
```

Or if you dont like a lot messing with curly braces:

```
module.exports.HelloWorld = function(event) {
    console.log('hello world!');
}

module.exports.AnotherFunction = function(event) {
    console.log('hello from another!');
}
```

*There are also other styles you can use:* https://gist.github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/10848413

Then in your **index.js** file import the file as a module:

```
const ifunctions = require('./internalFunctions');
```

And then you can call it directly within your triggers or HTTP handlers:

```
ifunctions.HelloWorld();
```

---

**Example:**

```
//Code to load modules 
//...
const ifunctions = require('./internalFunctions');

exports.myTrigger = functions.database.ref('/myNode/{id}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

      //Some of your code...        

      ifunctions.HelloWorld();

      //A bit more of code...

});
```

Comment: I have additional question, how to call a function at internalFunctions from internalFunctions? (within the same file)

Comment: Use `module.exports.HelloWorld();` or just `exports.HelloWorld();`

Comment: I mean like, inside HelloWorld() function, i want to call AnotherFunction() to process something, how do i call it?

Comment: Yes, within a function in internalFunctions.js you can use module.exports.HelloWorld(); to call a local function.

Comment: If you don't like it you can use another style of declaring and exporting your functions like the ones provided in the link of the answer: https://gist.github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/10848413

Comment: Are we still able to pass input to these functions from internalFunctions.js?