# firebase node.js/express.js add multiple firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am trying to add multiple firebase functions in the `index.ts` file following the example here: [How do I structure Cloud Functions for Firebase to deploy multiple functions from multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486278/how-do-i-structure-cloud-functions-for-firebase-to-deploy-multiple-functions-fro).

In particular, I have an `express.js` server which I initialized in `routes.ts`:

```
const server = express();
server.get('/api', (req, res) => res.send('hello /api'))
export {server}
```

Now In index.ts I can import `routes.ts` and also attach an user authentication listener so that when a new user is created, it fires, ie:

```
import {server} from './routers'

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(server);
exports.userEvents = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
    console.log("user created: ", user.email, user)
})
```

However so far as I can tell only `exports.app`  is actually working as intended, and `exports.userEvents` seem to not fire on new user creation.

=========================================================

EDIT:

The problem is how my `firebase.json` function is set up, it currently only serve `app` with endpoints starting with `/api/**`, ie:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",

    // the problem is here: you're not connecting to multiple functions
    "rewrites": [{
        "source": "/api/**"
      , "function": "app"  



      }],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

The questions is now how do I tell firebase to serve functions from`exports.userEvents` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was trying to simulate the functions in local environment. I had to deploy them for the non `http` functions to run. However there is a local emulator for other functions described at the bottom of the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff, which is new.