# Functions issues with Node 8 LTS?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I switched to Node 8 in my Cloud/Firebase Functions so I could access the spread operator to build [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52056785/1130342).

After doing so, it seems like deploys take about 2x the time and fail 80% of the time.

When they fail I get errors like

```
⚠  functions[projectsIndexDelete(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Build failed: Build error details not available
```

I never had these errors running Node 6 cloud functions.

Is this a known issue or did I miss a configuration step?

So far I have only added this snippet to `package.json`

```
"engines": {
  "node": "8"
},
```

Comment: Is your version of node >= 8.11.1 ?

Comment: I am on Node v10.6.0

Comment: Did you update Firebase CLI to at least version 4.0.0?

Comment: And update to version 2.0.1 for the firebase-functions module

Comment: firebase-tools: v4.2.0, firebase-functions: v2.0.5

Comment: `package-lock.json` shows I'm using `firebase-functions: v2.0.5`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178932/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-luke-pighetti).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [firebase-tool known issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/853) regarding the Node 8 version

Comment: I just switched back to Node 6, submitted a blank index.js file to delete my functions, and now everything is back to normal. I will not be using Node 8 until the community agrees it is production ready.

Comment: Ugh still seems to be ongoing issue in Jan 2019 :-(.

Comment: Indeed, [is still ongoing](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/853#issuecomment-451340372)