# socketPath equivalent for mySQL connection in TypeORM

Tags: mysql, firebase, google-cloud-platform, typeorm

I created a mySQL database in the [google cloud](https://cloud.google.com) and I'm trying to connect to the mySQL instance from [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023107/how-to-connect-google-cloud-sql-from-cloud-functions) on stackoverflow we need to set the socketPath property of mySql connection but TypeORM hasn't the same property wondering is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for lives in "extra" in your ormconfig. Here's an example that connects up to cloud SQL successfully for me:

```
{
"type": "mysql",
"extra": {
    "socketPath": "/cloudsql/<project>:<region>:<database>"
    },
"port": 3306,
"username": "myuser",
"password": "secret",
"database": "mydb"
}
```