# Connecting Static IP Cloud Functions to Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-networking

There are several good answers available for both of these scenarios - but not combined.

**1. I need to make a call to an external API via whitelisted static
    IP.**

 See: [Associating Cloud Function egress with a static IP address](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip)

 **a)** call the external API from the Cloud Function

 **b)** route all egress from this Cloud Function through a VPC Connector on vpcnetwork-1 (IP address range = 10.8.10.0/28)

**c)** use a Cloud NAT
    that routes all traffic on vpcnetwork-1 through [STATIC IP]
    (whitelisted by external API)

**2. Next, I need to take that API data and send it to a Cloud SQL
    instance (MySQL in this case).**

 See: [Connecting to Cloud SQL from Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions)

**a)** create a UNIX socketpath
    connection to [Cloud SQL Instance]

When I run with the VPC Connector (as shown above), I get:

**1)** SUCCESS! I've received the API data using my whitelisted IP address

**2)** CONNECTION REFUSED by [Cloud SQL Instance] - because I'm using a static external IP?  Does socketpath use external, or connect within my Google Cloud Project?

If I remove the VPC Connector from my Cloud Function, then I get:

**1)**  CONNECTION REFUSED - this IP is not whitelisted (because I'm no longer using the static IP)

**2)**  SUCCESS! I'm now able to connect to [Cloud SQL Instance] (using UNIX socketpath, userid, password)

How can I get both of these to work from the same Cloud Function?

 I see that I can "Route only requests to private IPs through the VPC connector" but I really want the opposite of that.  I want to only route external requests to the VPC connector, to use my static IP, and then keep my private routing for connections within my GCP.

ADDED: I am using [Javascript mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options) to connect to Cloud SQL.

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({ socketPath: '/cloudsql/[instance_connection_name]',
                              user: uid,
                              password: pwd,
                              database: 'mysql_db' });
var result = pool.query(sql, {}, (err,result)=> {});
```

This works ok without using a VPC Connector.  When I use a VPC Connector with a static external IP address, this connection is refused.  Is it because the VPC Connector and Cloud SQL instance are not on the same VPC?  I don't think Cloud SQL is linked to a VPC, is it?

Comment: Can you post the code of connecting from cloud function to clodsql. I wrote an answer how  this should be done in python [CONNECTING FROM GOOGLE CLOUD FUNCTIONS TO CLOUD SQL USING TCP AND UNIX DOMAIN SOCKETS 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023107/how-to-connect-google-cloud-sql-from-cloud-functions)

Comment: You should be able to connect from your cloud function to cloud sql , using vpc connector  and internal ip address of your cloud SQL instance (tcp). I have this is my post.

Comment: @marian.vladoi I am connecting using Javascript mysql

`var pool = mysql.createPool({
socketPath: '/cloudsql/[instance_connection_name]',
user: uid,
password: pwd,
database: 'mysql_db' 
});
var result = pool.query(sql, {}, (err,result)=> {});`

How can I check if this is using a TCP connection?  It works ok when I am not using the VPC connector.  When I connect this function through the VPC connector, this connection gives "CONNECTION REFUSED".

Comment: assuming you did step 9 on my previous answer, creating a service account and assign the right permission to your cloud function, you have to create a cloud sql instance only with internall ip and connect to the internal ip address of the instance, use `host:internall_ip_cloudsql` instead of `socketPath`, pay attention on my previous answer and check how i create the database, how I create the service accout, how I create the vpc connector and how I deploy the cloud function, I was able to connect using python

Comment: your connection string should look like this :  `var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : '10.36.0.3(internal ip of cloud sql instance)',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'guess',
    port: 3306  }); `

Comment: @marian.vladoi I got it to work - thanks.  First, I got it working with the Public IP, then I went through your instructions and was able to get Private IP working - it's a little trickier.  The Cloud Functions control panel has an option to "Route only requests to private IPs through the VPC connector".  For this use, I needed the opposite of that, which doesn't exist.  But your walk-through got me to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud SQL Instance Overview dashboard lists both [Public IP Address] and [Instance Connection Name]

For a standard Cloud Functions connection, I use:

```
socketpath:[Instance Connection Name]
user: uid
password: pwd
database: 'mysql_db'
```

When using a VPC Connector, I use

```
host:[Private (or Public) IP Address]
user: uid
password: pwd
database: 'mysql_db'
```

Summary:

```
[Cloud Function] -> socketpath:[Instance Connection Name] => **SUCCESS**
[Cloud Function] -> host:[Public IP Address] => **FAIL** (Timeout - IP Not Allowed)

Private VPC Connections:
[Cloud Function] -> [VPC Connector] -> socketpath:[Instance Connection Name] => **FAIL** (Connection Refused)
[Cloud Function] -> [VPC Connector] -> host:[Private IP Address] => **SUCCESS** (Set up Private IP in GCP->SQL->Connections)

Public VPC Connection:
[Cloud Function] -> [VPC Connector] -> host:[Public IP Address] => **SUCCESS** (Only after allowing/whitelisting IP of the VPC Connector routed through Cloud NAT)
```

Google Cloud CLI instructions for Private IP setup:

[CONNECTING FROM GOOGLE CLOUD FUNCTIONS TO CLOUD SQL USING TCP AND UNIX DOMAIN SOCKETS 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023107/how-to-connect-google-cloud-sql-from-cloud-functions)

Comment: can you please describe this line:[Cloud Function] -> [VPC Connector] -> host:[Public IP Address] => **SUCCESS** (Only after allowing IP of the routed VPC Connector), how do you allow the internal ip of the Vpc connector.

Comment: @marian.vladoi I edited to clarify that is a Public connection.  The reason I'm using the VPC Connector for this function is so I can route traffic through a Cloud NAT to a Static IP and make Public external API calls.  I was using that method before I used your example to create a Private connection - which should be more secure.