# Setting NODE_ENV for firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am moving some of my `firebase-queue` workers to Firebase Functions. I have used `process.env.NODE_ENV` to set some of the configuration for the workers depending on the environment in which I am running them. Is there a way to set the `NODE_ENV` for the functions while deploying them. I understand that the recommended way to provide such config options is via `firebase.config.set` which I have verified works as expected but just wanted to check if there is a way to set the `NODE_ENV` also. When I try to print out the `NODE_ENV` inside of a function, it is always set to `production`.

Comment: see  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

Comment: NODE_ENV in firebase is based on your project, so it's only really useful for things like changing variables between dev & production projects

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following Google's `Best practices and reserved environment variables` in their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var)

> Environment variables that are provided by the environment might change in future runtime versions. As a best practice, we recommend that you do not depend on or modify any environment variables that you have not set explicitly.

Basically don't use `NODE_ENV`. Use your own environment variables and set them accordingly.

**NOTE:** This documentations is from Google Cloud Functions. Firebase functions are like a wrapper around google cloud functions. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854865/what-is-the-difference-between-cloud-functions-and-firebase-functions)

Answer (score 10):

There is currently no way to set custom environment variables such as `process.env.NODE_ENV`. What you want to do can only be done for Google Cloud functions and you need to use the `gcloud` command-line tool.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#accessing_environment_variables_at_runtime

## Other options

If you are developing specifically for Firebase and need a similar solution, then there are options.

### Conditions based on project ID

You can access the project id if you are having test, staging and production projects and want to have different behavior or logging depending on the environment.

`process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT` is set to your GCP project ID so you can build logic based on that.

```js
if (process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT === 'my-production-project') {
  // Only in production
} else {
  // Do something for the test environments
}
```

### Cloud Function Environment Variables

As you already mentioned there's the cloud functions environment variables also. You can effectively create build pipelines that are configuring your environment configuration upon build/deploy and later access them in your cloud function.

```
- firebase functions:config:set runtime.env="production" --token $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY
```

Accessing the configuration is effectively the same as your `process.env` but can not be accessed outside of the scope of a cloud function (i.e. you can't use it in a global variable declaration).

```js
if (functions.config().runtime.env === 'production') {
  // Only in production
} else {
  // Do something for the test environments
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At the time I'm answering this question the **Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions offers built-in environment configuration out of the box**.

### Set environment configuration for your project

```sh
$ firebase functions:config:set [values...]
```

### Example

```sh
$ firebase functions:config:set someservice.key="THE API KEY" someservice.id="THE CLIENT ID"
```

---

### Get environment configuration for your project

```sh
$ firebase functions:config:get [path]
```

### Example

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
console.log(functions.config().someservice.id)
```

---

NOTE: [You must redeploy functions to make the new configuration available.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env)