# NODE_ENV variable is automatically set to 'production' when deploying to Firebase hosting

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting, reactjs

I am building a React.js app with Firebase and cannot figure out why when I am running locally, `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` in App.js always returns `development`, but when deploying to hosting it is always `production`.

In my .env file, I have `NODE_ENV='production'` or `NODE_ENV='development'`, which I change before I build depending on which Firebase project alias I am deploying to. When I deploy to my Firebase development project, I always get the NODE_ENV to be 'production' because (I have read that) NODE_ENV gets set when npm building automatically. Is there a way for me to prevent this so when I deploy, it will stay as `development`? Or maybe I am doing this wrong? Anything helps, thanks!

**.env**

```
# Live
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_LIVE_API_KEY=..
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_LIVE_AUTH_DOMAIN=..
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_LIVE_DATABASE_URL=..

# Test 
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_TEST_API_KEY=..
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_TEST_AUTH_DOMAIN=..
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_TEST_DATABASE_URL=..

# Other
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
NODE_ENV='production'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting NODE\_ENV for firebase function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139959/setting-node-env-for-firebase-function)

Comment: @AritraChakraborty no, I am using the NODE_ENV in the React.js project directory only, not in my firebase functions.

Comment: I am running into the same problem.. I don't get at all the issue

Comment: @Emixam23 I never got an answer to this, so maybe you can’t change that NODE_ENV variable

Comment: I found out that you can’t update this variable for some security against developers.. I found out that using ‘cmd-env’ was the answer at the end.. just make sure you build with the correct env file because it’s used at building time, not deploy/start/run time

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.env.local` and add `NODE_ENV="development"` to it. When you build the app, this version will take precedence.