# How can I use nodemailer with Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, nodemailer, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com) in a [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiy3IXgpZfTAhXhB5oKHX3XDP8QFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Ffunctions%2F&usg=AFQjCNFdWm1QGO5vqjgc-GQ9UjC_XotMlQ&sig2=dHWfybYbAMvBtLHLU7c3Bw&bvm=bv.152174688,d.bGs) but keep getting errors seeming to be that the smpt server cant be reached or found. Iv'e tried gmail, outlook and a normal hosted smpt service. It works well from my local node server.

This is the logged error I receive from the failed attempt to send email:

```
{
  Error: getaddrinfoENOTFOUNDsmtp-mail.outlook.comsmtp-mail.outlook.com: 587aterrnoException(dns.js: 28: 10)atGetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup[
    asoncomplete
  ](dns.js: 76: 26)code: 'ECONNECTION',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
  host: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
  port: '587',
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

Comment: That tag doesn't exists. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854865/what-is-the-difference-between-cloud-function-and-firebase-functions

Comment: Is the project that you run the function in on a paid plan? Projects on the free/Spark plan cannot call out to external services (to prevent the potential abuse).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It's on the free/Spark so that is probably the issue. To bad it did not work with gmail though.

Answer (score 4):

I created a cloud function (http event) to send emails from the contact form section of my site with the following way:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const rp = require('request-promise');

//google account credentials used to send email
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(
    `smtps://user@domain.com:password@smtp.gmail.com`);

exports.sendEmailCF = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  //recaptcha validation
  rp({
        uri: 'https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
        method: 'POST',
        formData: {
            secret: 'your_secret_key',
            response: req.body['g-recaptcha-response']
        },
        json: true
    }).then(result => {
        if (result.success) {
            sendEmail('recipient@gmail.com', req.body).then(()=> { 
              res.status(200).send(true);
            });
        }
        else {
            res.status(500).send("Recaptcha failed.")
        }
    }).catch(reason => {
        res.status(500).send("Recaptcha req failed.")
    })

});

// Send email function
function sendEmail(email, body) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `<noreply@domain.com>`,
    to: email
  };
  // hmtl message constructions
  mailOptions.subject = 'contact form message';
  mailOptions.html = `<p><b>Name: </b>${body.rsName}</p>
                      <p><b>Email: </b>${body.rsEmail}</p>
                      <p><b>Subject: </b>${body.rsSubject}</p>
                      <p><b>Message: </b>${body.rsMessage}</p>`;
  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
}
```

Comment: Did you test it? I'm doing something similar and it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, did it.  Please see a more detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833384/implementing-sending-email-with-firebase-cloud-functions/46255823#46255823