# Firebase Cloud Functions to send an HTTP request on a user sign-in trigger?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm sorry, but I've watched all seven of [Jennifer Person's videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=vr0Gfvp5v1A), read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), and worked through the tutorials but I still don't see how to write my function. I'm trying to write a function that gets an IBM Watson Speech-to-text token, which is obtained with this CURL script:

```
curl -X GET --user username:password --output token
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api"
```

I.e., send an HTTP GET request to the URL, provide my username and password, and then write the output to the file `/javascript/services/token`.

This is my guess as to the function. An authentication trigger wraps a Nodejs HTTP GET request, and a NodeJs file save `fs.writefile`.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.getWatsonToken = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => { // authentication trigger

  var https = require('https');  // Nodejs http.request

  var options = {
    host: 'stream.watsonplatform.net',
    path: '/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api',
    username: groucho,
    password: swordfish
  };

  callback = function(response) {
    response.on('end', function () {
      console.log(response);
      fs.writeFile("/javascript/services/token", response);
    });
  }

  http.request(options, callback).end();

});
```

Comment: Regarding the missing tag--because Cloud Functions for Firebase is a wrapper around Google Cloud Functions, that tag is used.  See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42859932/4815718

Comment: Did you check billing is enabled for your Firebase project? Because you cannot call external url. It's limitation of free account

Comment: You can't just write to arbitrary files on a Cloud Functions instance.  You can write to /tmp.  But that isn't guaranteed to stick around.  Why do you need data in a file?  What's the end game?

Comment: Cloud Functions are meant to be state-less, so store that file in Firebase Storage, or write it to the database, don't leave on the file system as it won't stay stored.

Answer (score 2):

This function works:

```
// Node modules
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const request = require('request'); // node module to send HTTP requests
const fs = require('fs');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.getWatsonToken = functions.database.ref('userLoginEvent').onUpdate(event => { // authentication trigger when user logs in

  var username = 'groucho',
      password = 'swordfish',
      url = 'https://' + username + ':' + password + '@stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api';

  request({url: url}, function (error, response, body) {

    var tokenService = "app.value('watsonToken','" + body + "');";

    fs.writeFile('../public/javascript/services/watsonTokenValue.js', tokenService, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
        console.log('The file has been saved!');
    }); // close fs.writeFile

  }); // close request

}); // close getWatsonToken
```

In the controller:

```
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) { // this runs on login
    if (user) { // user is signed in
      console.log("User signed in!");
      $scope.authData = user;
      firebase.database().ref('userLoginEvent').update({'user': user.uid}); // update Firebase database to trigger Cloud Function to get a new IBM Watson token
    } // end if user is signed in
    else { // User is signed out
      console.log("User signed out.");
    }
  }); // end onAuthStateChanged
```

Walking through the Cloud Function, it injects four Node modules, including `request` for sending HTTP requests, and `fs` for writing the results to a file. Then the trigger is set for an update to a location `userLoginEvent` in the Firebase database (which I created from the console). Next, the HTTP request goes out. The response (the token) is called `body.app.value('watsonToken','" + body + "');` is an Angular value service to wrap the token. Then `fs` writes all this to a location in my project.

In the AngularJS controller, `onAuthStateChanged` triggers when a user logins in. The user.uid is then updated to the location `userLoginEvent` in the Firebase database, and the Cloud Function triggers, the HTTP request goes out, and the response is written to an Angular service.

Comment: For your solution to work, I believe you have to be running something other than [the Spark (free) plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/). Can you please please confirm you are using either Flame or Blaze (paid) plan? Also, I'm curious which you chose.