# Firebase database versus cloud services

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Can anyone explain the major differences between the firebase "database" and the firebase "cloud functions". It is my understanding database is where you store information for your application, but how does the cloud functions work? Is this the same database, or a separate one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database is a NoSQL database. Cloud Functions for Firebase are functions you can run based upon events triggered by Firebase features, including the Database, Cloud Storage, Authentication,  and Analytics. Cloud Functions are not a database at all. The code for Cloud Functions is stored in Google's cloud and runs in a managed environment. Please see the documentation for more information on [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) and the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/).

Comment: I have worked with MySQL in the past, but not NoSQL. I will have to read more about it. Thanks for confirming that all the Firebase functions can be connected, as my fear was to develop using one and then need to switch later on.

Comment: Also see [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) and [What is "Firebase Functions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854865/what-is-the-difference-between-cloud-function-and-firebase-functions) (hint: it's not what you're referring to).