# Deploy to Firebase without cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I try to deploy my Firebase app, I get the following error:

> Error: Cloud Functions deployment requires the pay-as-you-go (Blaze) billing plan.

I no longer want to use Cloud Functions on my app, and I have no references to Cloud Functions in my code. How can I now deploy my app without Cloud Functions?

Comment: If not Cloud Functions, then what **are** you trying to deploy?

Comment: What does the firebase.json look like, and what command are we using to deploy?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558824/delete-all-firebase-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1) question may help you out. It might be necessary to remove all the old functions that are currently deployed to Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just deploying hosting you can say so

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

this will not deploy functions