# How do I reset a value in a database every day in firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Let's say I have a value at

```
"/nullable/uid/"
```

and it has this line:

```
daily_rep: 10
```

and so, how to make this `daily_rep` become `0` every day, let's say at `22: 00`

what do you need to do for this? for example, use Firebase Functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for such operations in the Firebase Realtime Database, so you'll need to use an external mechanism to perform such an operation.

Cloud Functions for Firebase are definitely a great option for this, as they have a built-in capability to [run functions on a schedule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions). But honestly, any other place where you can run code on a schedule could probably work too, as long as you can access the database through one of the Firebase SDKs or through the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start).

Comment: Firebase Functions maybe?

Comment: That is (for all intents and purposes of this question) the same Cloud Functions for Firebase. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854865/what-is-the-difference-between-cloud-functions-and-firebase-functions if you'd like to learn the subtle differences.