# FirebaseAuthError in firebase function while generating custom auth token using createCustomToken

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to move my custom authentication code from a `firebase-queue` worker to a firebase function. I am getting following error when I try to call the `createCustomToken` method.

Below is the code that I am using to create the custom token

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims ? additionalClaims : {})
```

Below it the error on the Firebase Functions dashboard

```
Error: createCustomToken() requires a certificate with "private_key" set.
    at FirebaseAuthError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:25:28)
    at new FirebaseAuthError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:90:23)
    at FirebaseTokenGenerator.createCustomToken (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/token-generator.js:62:19)
    at Auth.createCustomToken (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth.js:89:37)
    at Object.generate (/user_code/helpers/AuthTokenGenerator.js:7:37)
    at ref.child.child.once.then (/user_code/index.js:59:35)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
```

Similar function works currently in the `firebase-queue` worker implementation but there I initialize the app using the service account as suggested on the docs. I am guessing the problem is with the `initializeApp` call but this is how it is suggested on the Firebase Functions doc.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717540/firebase-cloud-functions-createcustomtoken/42724251#42724251

Answer (score 2):

Your application default credentials are not sufficient to mint custom tokens, you'll need pass a [service account certificate](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk) to `initializeApp`.

You can see this in action in our [LinkedIn auth example on Github](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/linkedin-auth).