# Generating a custom auth token with a cloud function for firebase using the new 1.0 SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

As of `firebase-admin@5.11.0` and `firebase-functions@1.0.0` `firebase-admin` no longer takes in an application config when the app initializes.

I had a firestore function that would generate a custom token using firebase-admin’s `createCustomToken`. Calling that function would generate a credential that I would pass into `initializeApp` in the `credential` attribute. How would I go about doing that now?

Do I need to edit `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG` somehow and put the serialized credential there before calling `initializeApp`?

Answer (score 5):

Based on this issue in Github, it still works.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/224

The following example worked for me:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://yourapplication.firebaseio.com/'
  });

exports.createToken = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    return admin.auth()
                .createCustomToken(uid)
                .then(customToken => {
                    console.log(`The customToken is: ${customToken}`);
                    return {status: 'success', customToken: customToken};
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(`Something happened buddy: ${error}`)
                    return {status: 'error'};
                });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although it is a great idea to provide a link to the source (as you have done). It is also a good idea to copy the relevant text/code into your answer as well. That way if the link changes content or stops working your answer still has value.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Chen's cloud function appears to trigger from a HTTP request from somewhere (an external server?). My employee wrote a cloud function that triggers when the user logs in:

```
// this watches for any updates to the user document in the User's collection (not subcollections)
exports.userLogin = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}').onUpdate((change, context) => {

  // save the userID ubtained from the wildcard match, which gets put into context.params
  let uid = context.params.userID;
  // initialize basic values for custom claims
  let trusted = false;
  let teaches = [];

  // check the Trusted_Users doc
  admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc('Trusted_Users').get()
  .then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.data().UIDs.includes(uid)) {
      // if the userID is in the UIDs array of the document, set trusted to true.
      trusted = true;
    }

    // Get docs for each language in our dictionary
    admin.firestore().collection('Dictionaries').get()
    .then(function(docs) {
      // for each of those language docs
      docs.forEach(function(doc) {
        // check if the userID is included in the trustedUIDs array in the doc
        if (doc.data().trustedUIDs.includes(uid)) {
          // if it is, we push the 2-letter language abbreviation onto the array of what languages this user teaches
          teaches.push(doc.data().shortLanguage);
        }
      });

      // finally, set custom claims as we've parsed
      admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {'trusted': trusted, 'teaches': teaches}).then(() => {
        console.log("custom claims set.");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

First, we put in a `lastLogin` property on the user object, which runs Date.now when a user logs in and writes the time to the database location, triggering the cloud function.

Next, we get the `userID` from the cloud function response `context.params.userID`.

Two variables are then initialized. We assume that the user is not trusted until proven otherwise. The other variable is an array of subjects the user teaches. In a roles-based data security system, these are the collections that the user is allowed to access.

Next, we access a document listing the userIDs of trusted users. We then check if the recently logged in userID is in this array. If so, we set `trusted` to `true`.

Next, we go to the database and traverse a collection `Dictionaries` whose documents include arrays of trusted userIDs (i.e., users allowed to read and write those documents). If the user is in one or more of these arrays, he or she gets that document added to the `teaches` property on his or her user data, giving the user access to that document.

Finally, we're ready to run `setCustomUserClaims` to customize the token claims.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation for a Callable Cloud Function, thanks to  [Thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51659122/2162226)

Once the custom claim is set, you can access the field in/from .. say, a firebase storage rule.

For example:
`allow write: if request.auth.token.isAppAdmin == true;`

With a Callable Cloud Function, as long as the `admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(..)` function is returned somewhere along the promise chain, the claim field will be added to the `request.auth.token` object:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.setIsAdminClaim = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    var uid = context.auth.uid;
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(
            uid, {
                isAppAdmin: true
            }
        )
        .then(() => {
            var msg = 'isAppAdmin custom claim set';
            console.log(msg);

            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                var resolveObject = {

                    message : msg
                };

                resolve(resolveObject);
            });
        });
});
```