# Firebase admin.auth().createCustomToken(userId) occurred "auth/internal-error: Request contains an invalid argument"

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm using `firebase-admin` on a node server

Initializing the admin app works fine:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
  serviceAccountId: '***.apps.googleusercontent.com'
});
```

Here's the code I create a custom token and send back to client.

```
  const userId = 'some-uid';
  admin.auth().createCustomToken(userId).then((customToken) => {
    console.log(customToken);
    res.send(customToken);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  });
```

The error is occurred at line `admin.auth().createCustomToken(userId)`:

> code: 'auth/internal-error',
>
> message: 'Request contains an invalid argument.; Please refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens for more details on how to use and troubleshoot this feature. Raw server response: "{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Request contains an invalid argument.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}"'

I followed the links below and I don't find any address to solve this

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors

Comment: Have you tried it with a valid UID?

Comment: I don't know what you mean a valid UID. Because follow the document https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens said that: "At a minimum, you need to provide a uid, which can be any string but should uniquely identify the user or device you are authenticating.". So I just tried a random string. Sorry If I have any misunderstand.

Comment: It's just a hunch, I don't know either. But does `createCustomToken` require an actual user ID from Firebase Auth? If yes, then a random string wouldn't match any user in Firebase Auth - maybe that's why you get a 400 error. Try it with an actual ID from your Firebase Auth system and find out.

Comment: I passed a UID in the Firebase Authentication Users console, and still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way to initialize the admin, this function works properly.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json")

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com',
  serviceAccountId: '***.apps.googleusercontent.com'
});
```

For more detail please refer to these links:

- [Generating a custom auth token with a cloud function for firebase using the new 1.0 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49656429/generating-a-custom-auth-token-with-a-cloud-function-for-firebase-using-the-new)
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

I don't know why it works, cause following this issue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/224#issuecomment-390424993, the "creating custom tokens without a service account" feature is implemented. But these changes work for me. Hope it helps!!!